# Issue with code to post testimonial

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a code to post testimonials to database but it is not working. All the variables are set but when submitting my form, returns the following error:"Problem while submitting testimonial". Kindly assist me to troubleshoot. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$province=$_POST['province'];
$testimonial=$_POST['testimonial'];

// TIME
$postedon="3456787654";
// TIME



// SENTIMENT

$state="1";

// SENTIMENT



if ($state==true) {
// insert into database

require 'ddbconfig.php';


$insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO d_tbltestimonias 
(id,d_name,d_address,d_city,d_province,d_testimonial,postedon,state)
VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$province', 
'".addslashes($testimonial)."','$postedon', '$state')");

if ($insert==true) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.top.location.href='testimonials.php?posted';
</script>
<?php
}else{
echo "Problem while submitting testimonial";
}
// insert into database
}

?>
```

Comment: See about prepared statements . This is NOT how to protect yourself against SQL injection

Comment: remove ID from insert parameters "id,"

Comment: Use proper MySqli query built method - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Also, you appear to have 8 columns and 7 values. How's that supposed to work?

Comment: You check there’s an error. That’s good. But you don’t check *which* error it is. That would explain things to you. Use `mysqli_error`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO d_tbltestimonias 
 (d_name,d_address,d_city,d_province,d_testimonial,postedon,state)
 VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$province', 
 '".addslashes($testimonial)."','$postedon', '$state')";

 $insert = $con->query($sql);

 if ($insert === true) {
 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.top.location.href='testimonials.php?posted';
  </script>
 <?php
  }else{
    echo "Problem while submitting testimonial";
   }
  }
```

Comment: this code will solve the OP problem but at least suggest him/her to use safe query or prepared statement and give the some explanation about your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems in your code.

1. Remove id from the defined query.
2. This type of query will not protect yourself against SQL injection.
3. Did not handle properly error.